# Create Calculate Measure Based On One Dimension And 2 Relations In SSAS

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube, measure, multidimensional-cube

Please Consider this Fact Table:

```
Sender           Receiver         Amount
----------------------------------------
Reseller1        Resseler2        100 
Reseller1        Resseler3        200
Reseller3        Resseler1        150
Reseller3        Resseler2        50
Reseller1        Resseler4        100
Reseller4        Resseler2        350
Reseller4        Resseler1        500
Reseller4        Resseler3        250
```

I want create a calculate Measures based on this formula: `Sum(Receiver)-Sum(Sender)` and create such this result:

```
Reseller             Amount
---------------------------
Reseller1             250    <---- (500 + 150) - (100 + 200 + 100)
Reseller2             500    <---- (100 + 50 + 350) - (0)
Reseller3             250    <---- (200 + 250) - (150 + 50)
Reseller4             -1000  <---- (100) - (350 + 500 + 250)
```

How can I create calculate measure for this?

Thanks

---

My `DimReseller` is:

```
ResellerCode            ResellerName
---------------------------------------
1                        Reseller1
2                        Reseller2
3                        Reseller3
4                        Reseller4
```

and it has two relationship with `Sender` and `Receiver`

---

**Edit 1)**

Based on Master @Saeid Yousefi's answer:

My structure is:

[image]

[image]

I wrote this `MDX` query:

```
WITH 
MEMBER SenderAmount AS
    [Measures].[Amount], FORMAT_STRING = "Standard"

MEMBER ReceiverAmount AS
     (LinkMember   
     ([Sender].[Hierarchy].CurrentMember, [Receiver].[Hierarchy])  
     ,[Measures].[Amount]), FORMAT_STRING = "Standard"

MEMBER DiffAmount AS
  ReceiverAmount - SenderAmount, FORMAT_STRING = "Standard"

SELECT    {SenderAmount, ReceiverAmount, DiffAmount} ON 0,
[Sender].[Hierarchy].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM [Reseller Sales]
```

but I got `null` for receiver amount:

[image]

I know there is a small problem but I can't fix that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes in a data warehouse a dimension is connected to a fact table in more than one way, these ways  can  be  created  using  direct  or  indirect  links between Dim  and  Fact,  therefore  we  can  use a dimension to analyze Fact values in different roles; these dimensions are called Role-Playing Dimensions.
When designing a cube, for each role of the dimension, a new instance of dimension will be added to the cube. 
Given  these  circumstances, each  dimension  will  analyze  the  cube  and  although  you  can  use  multiple dimensions  in  a  report  but  in  Members  level  these  dimensions  are  distinguished. With  these  said, sometimes we feel the need to select a member to be the representative of all roles of a dimension given the situation, this is when Link Member function jumps in to aid us.

This  function  takes  two arguments:

- Member Expression: An MDX expression which returns a member.
- Hierarchy Expression: An MDX expression which returns a hierarchy.

This function returns the member equivalent to a specified member in a specified hierarchy.

So, your code should be something like following:

```
WITH 
MEMBER SenderAmount AS
    [Measures].[Amount], FORMAT_STRING = "Standard"

MEMBER ReceiverAmount AS
      (LinkMember   
         ([Sender].[Hierarchy].CurrentMember, [Receiver].[Hierarchy])  
         ,[Measures].[Amount]
         ,[Sender].[Hierarchy].[All]), FORMAT_STRING = "Standard"

MEMBER DiffAmount AS
      ReceiverAmount - SenderAmount, FORMAT_STRING = "Standard"

SELECT    {SenderAmount, ReceiverAmount, DiffAmount} ON 0,
NON EMPTY [Sender].[Hierarchy].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM [Cube]
```

Please pay attention to LinkMember function which is working on role-playing dimensions. So, [Sender] and [Receiver] are the names of your dimensions which are attached to your cube, you can find the name of those in `Dimension Usage` tab of your cube. Also, [Hierarchy] is the name of your attribute or standard hierarchy, so according to the screenshot of your dimension configuration, it should be [Dimension Name] + either [Hierarchy].[Reseller Code].members or [Reseller Code].members or [Hierarchy].members depending on what you want.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Saeid Yousefi. You are great. You are like @JohnSkeet in BI. I have a small problem and I wanted to ask you to see **Edit 1** please.

Answer (score 2):

Sample approach to your task:

1. In DSV - create two tables (as SQL named queries) with `Sender - Amount` and `Receiver - Amount` columns. Thus you effectively split Sellers and Receivers data.
2. On Cube - create two measure groups with Sum aggregation on Amount column and linked to DimReseller dim.
3. Create a Calc measure as `[Measures].[Receiver Amount] - [Measures].[Sender Amount]`

Comment: @Arian, if you wish let's conrinue in chat room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204468/seller-receiver-measure